# My class doesn't seem to map correctly with an API's JSON response, not binding

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having issues with deserializing a JSON response.

```
userResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(result);
```

The json response looks like:

```
{
    "Results" : [
        {
            "Id" :  1,
            "Name" : "John",
            "Age"  : 50
        }
    ],
    "Paging" : {
        "TotalPages" : 5,
        "CurrentPage" : 1
    }
}
```

My UserResponse class that is suppose to bind to the JSON above looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserResponse
{
    [DateMember(Name = "Results" )]
    public List<User> Results {get;set;}

    [DateMember(Name = "Paging" )]
    public Paging Paging {get;set;}

}

[DataContract]
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Paging
{
    public int TotalPages {get;set;}    
    public int CurrentPage {get;set;}
}
```

Does the current UserResponse look have any issues with it?
I'm not sure why it isn't binding correctly.

The userResponse object is coming back not null, but the values of the properties are null.

Comment: I think it should be good

Comment: Looks perfect and when I load it up it works as expected. Can you clarify what you mean by userResponse being not null but the values of the properties are null. In the example you've given, the properties are definitely not null.

Comment: @TravisActon how did you test it?

Comment: Just copied your classes down then did a quick:             

string json = "{\"Results\" : [{\"Id\" :  1,\"Name\" : \"John\",\"Age\"  : 50}],\"Paging\" : {\"TotalPages\" : 5,\"CurrentPage\" : 1}}";

var userResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(json);

Comment: @coolbreeze Because you are using data contract you need to include the data members on the other classes as well. Using data contract is all or nothing. So either remove all or have everything properly adorned with their attributes

Comment: @Nkosi is right, in my test I was not decorating the classes with a data contract and as soon as I did that, it returns null. If you decorate with [DataMember] above your properties then the properties are returned again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using `DataContract` you need to include the `DataMember` attribute on the other classes as well. Using `DataContract` is all or nothing.

If you look at Json.Net documentation about [DataContract and DataMember Attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm)

```
[DataContract]
public class File
{
    // excluded from serialization
    // does not have DataMemberAttribute
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Note the comment in the example.

So to solve your problem, either remove all `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse
{
    public List<User> Results { get; set; }
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
}
```

**or** have everything properly adorned with their respective attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class User {
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Paging {
    [DataMember]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class UserResponse {
    [DataMember]
    public List<User> Results { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure:

```
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
}
```